# Не удается получить значение массива

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress, объекты, woocommerce

Есть магазин wordpress+woocommerce. Мне нужно вывести краткое описание определенного товара - для этого запрашиваю:

```
$order = new WC_Order($id);
var_dump($order);
```

в результате чего получаю:

```
object(WC_Order)#9903 (14) { ["order_type"]=> string(6) "simple" ["id"]=> int(5666) ["post"]=> object(WP_Post)#9900 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(5666) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2015-12-15 11:07:23" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2015-12-15 08:07:23" ["post_content"]=> string(67) "Текстовое описание" ["post_title"]=> string(30) "Название" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(174) "Описание"... }
```

Пытаюсь обратиться к полям массива и вывести значение поля `["post_excerpt"]`:

```
$description = $order->post_excerpt;
$desc = $order["post_excerpt"];
echo $description; //выводится пусто
echo $desc; //дальше контент не читается
```

Как правильно получить контент?

Comment: `$order->post->post_excerpt;`

Answer (score 1):

2 решения:

1. `$order->post->post_excerpt;`
2. или сразу без создания массива, что проще:

   `$product_expert = get_post($id)->post_excerpt;`